# Python for loop items in single array

Tags: python, arrays

How can I convert incoming for loop items into a single array?

```py
for txn in txn_card:
    text = txn.text
    text = np.array([text])
    print(text)
```

Desired output:
`[[item1] ,[item2] ,[item3]]`

Comment: is `np.array(txn_card).reshape(-1,1)` what you're looking for?

Comment: Current Output comes as row:
[item1]
[item1]
[item1]

required Output:
[[item1]
,[item2]
,[item3]]

Comment: Perhaps, you include the comment into the question.

Comment: @florent Monin your code gives a result like this [[item1]] [[item2]] [[item3]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your 'comment', you may try something along the line of list comprehension

```py
## define 'items'
#txn_card = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
##or
txn_card = [['item1'], ['item2'], ['item3']]

## Use a list comprehension to create the new array
#new_txn_card = np.array([item for item in txn_card])
new_txn_card = [item for item in txn_card]

## Print the new array
print(new_txn_card)
```

Comment: The comprehension here is redundant, you can use `new_txn_card = np.array(txn_card)`

Comment: Thanks @JonSG That's valuable input. Seems `new_txn_card = np.array(txn_card)` yields  `[['item1']
 ['item2']
 ['item3']]`